# How to get multiple outputs with an evaluate filter function in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter an excel table to only get the data of a certain group in vba. I am using the evaluate function to evaluate a filter function in vba. When I use the function directly in excel, the output is right and I get more than one cell of data. When I use the evaluate filter in vba, I only get the first cell of data as an output.
[image]

```
Sub Start_Time()

    Dim UGs(1 To 5) As Long
    Dim ST As String
    
    Dim r1 As Range
    Set r1 = Worksheets("s1").Range("B:B")
    
    Dim r2 As Range
    Set r2 = Worksheets("s1").Range("C:C")

    UGs(1) = 401
    UGs(2) = 402
    UGs(3) = 403
    UGs(4) = 404
    UGs(5) = 405
    
    For Each item In UGs
        Dim expr As String
            expr = "=Filter(" & _
               r1.Address & "," & _
               r2.Address & "=" & item & _
               ")"
               
            MsgBox expr
            
        Worksheets("s1").Cells(2, 4 + WhereInArray(UGs, item)).Value = Evaluate(expr)
        
    Next item
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to size the destination range to match the number of rows returned by Evaluate.  Note also that there are two versions of Evalute, you'll want to use the worksheet scoped version

Comment: So, all cells can have Formulas & Values.  You just asked VBA to evaluate (produce a value) and store it in the value field of that cell.  Try Worksheets("s1").Cells(2, 4 + WhereInArray(UGs, item)).Formula = expr.  That will put your formula into the cell.  You might have to use FormulaArray to get the range to print

Comment: `Dim res As Variant. Res = 
 Worksheets("s1").Evaluate(expr)   Worksheets("s1").Cells( ... ).Resize( UBound(res, 1)) = res`

Comment: You could just put the Filter formula in the cell and let it spill