# Passing VBA-defined array into excel's predefined function (e.g. using Application.Evaluate())

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering about the possibility of passing a VBA-defined array into excel's predefined dynamic functions such as "FILTER".

The VBA-FILTER function does not really do a good job as excel's Dynamic-FILTER function in terms of criteria -flexibility and -multiplicity. I know I can do something similar using while/for loop but it would be nice if we can utilize the excel pre-made functions. Not only for the FILTER function but for other excel functions too. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68028262/how-to-get-multiple-outputs-with-an-evaluate-filter-function-in-vba) Louis (regardless of his issue) used something similar but pass Range addresses instead of VBA-defined array addresses.

Here is a simplified example of what I wanted to do:

```
Sub Test()
    ' How to use/pass VBA defined array into excel functions (using evaluate)
    ' without using Range or Cells
    
    Dim SA(1 To 5, 1 To 1) As String
    Dim SB(1 To 5, 1 To 1) As Boolean
    SA(1, 1) = "Apple"
    SA(2, 1) = "Orange"
    SA(3, 1) = "Berry"
    SA(4, 1) = "Apple"
    SA(5, 1) = "Appricot"

    SB(1, 1) = True
    SB(2, 1) = True
    SB(3, 1) = Fales
    SB(4, 1) = True
    SB(5, 1) = Fales
    
    ex = "=FILTER(" & SA.Address & ", " & SB.Address & ")"     ' this line has error
    RST = Evaluate(ex)
    
    Worksheets("Add").Range("AG8:AG" & UBound(RST) + 7).Value2 = RST
End Sub
```

Please help

Comment: You don't need evaluate: `RST = Worksheetfunction.Filter(sa, sb)` (though your array needs to have `False` not `Fales`)

Comment: I think 'Worksheetfunction' pretty much addresses my questions. I was not aware of it.  Thank you @Rory for your comment.

Comment: Is it possible to have an expression similar to this `RST = Worksheetfunction.Filter(SA, SA = "Apple")` . I want to avoid the construction of SB (criteria results) through the while/for loop too.

Comment: Try using the [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filter-function?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008912)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) function, for example `RST = VBA.Filter(Application.Transpose(SA), "Apple", True, vbTextCompare)`

Comment: @Domenic I am not sure if it can accept multiple criteria like this `RST = Worksheetfunction.Filter(SA, (SA = "Apple") + (SA = "Orange") )`

Comment: In that case, I think you'll need to create a new array for the second argument that holds the boolean results of your comparison.

Comment: Unless there is another worksheet function exposed in VBA that will create the array (which will depend on what you're actually doing), you'll need a loop. For your single criterion, you could use `Application.Isnumber(application.search("Apple",sa))`